# Select top 3 values from variable, then next 3 etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, variables

I have this variable with images. I also have 3 div's in which I want to put the images.

```
var images = [
'dali.jpg',
'illusionisme.png',
'impresionisme.jpg',
'popart.jpg',
'abstracter.jpg',
'abstrat.jpg',
'concept.jpg',
'fingerpaint.jpg',
'flowers.jpg',
'graffiti.jpg',
'groovy.jpg',
'skelly.jpg',
'vangogh.jpg'
]
```

By using this code every div does get a random image, which is nice but not what I want. How can I use jQuery to put the first 3 images inside the 3 divs, then the second 3 images in the div?

```
$(".art").click(function(){
$(".art").each(function(){
    $(this).find("img").remove();
    $(this).prepend('<img src="assets/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)] + '">');
});
```

});

```
<div class="art">    
<div class="art">    
<div class="art">
```

Comment: not quite sure what you mean.. can you post an example of of the resulting html structure you'd like to see?

Comment: The first 3 each one in one div, and the next 3 in which div o.o?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post, I made a jsFiddle that will clear some things up, I hope. http://jsfiddle.net/vT4gs/1/ I have 3 divs (.art) these divs contain an image pulled from the top 3 from the variable. When a user clicks on a .art div I want to remove the current images and replace them with the next 3 images from the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, please elaborate if this is not what you are looking for..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/c7U7q/1/

where the code is giving just text now, you can wrap that text in an `<img src= />` to give you the images..

```
var images = [
'dali.jpg',
'illusionisme.png',
'impresionisme.jpg',
'popart.jpg',
'abstracter.jpg',
'abstrat.jpg',
'concept.jpg',
'fingerpaint.jpg',
'flowers.jpg',
'graffiti.jpg',
'groovy.jpg',
'skelly.jpg',
'vangogh.jpg'];

$(".art").click(function () {
   $(this).html(getNext3()); //images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]);
 });



 $('#startLoop').click(function () {
  loopImages();
 });

function loopImages(){
 var art = $('.art');
 art.fadeOut(1000, function () {
     art.html(getNext3()).fadeIn(1000, function() { loopImages(); });
 });
 }
var counter = 0;

function getNext3() {
  var imgs = "";
  //img src=...
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      imgs += ' ' + images[counter];
      counter++;
  }
  return imgs;
 }
```

**UPDATED**
(load 3 into 3 divs at a time.)

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/c7U7q/7/

```
function setNext3() {
 var imgs = "";
 //img src=...
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    imgs = images[counter];
    console.log(imgs);
    console.log(i);
    $("div.art:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").html(imgs);
    console.log($("div.art:nth-child(" + i + ")"));
    counter++;
 }

}
```

Comment: This is in the right direction. I like how you select the next 3 values from the images variable. But I want to store each result in a different div. 

First variable result = first div.
Second result = second div
Third result = third div
Fourth result = first div
Fith result = second div
Sixth result = third div

So in groups of 3 but in every div another result. If that makes sence.

Comment: I added your Fiddle a bit http://jsfiddle.net/c7U7q/5/ As you can see it puts the same result in every div but I want the next result in the next div...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the current image index and then add the number to increase the index by each click

html

```
<div class="art">
    <img data-imageindex="0" src="" />
</div>
<div class="art">
    <img data-imageindex="1" src="" />
</div>
<div class="art">
    <img data-imageindex="2" src="" />
</div>
```

js

```
var artLength = $(".art").length;
$(".art").click(function () {
    $(".art").each(function () {
        var $image = $(this).find("img");
        var nextImageIndex = $image.data("imageindex") + artLength;
        if (nextImageIndex >= images.length) {
            nextImageIndex -= images.length;
        }
        $image.data("imageindex", nextImageIndex).attr("src",
            "assets/images/" + images[nextImageIndex]);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44zB4/